# How to find the class of a checkbox that was clicked

Tags: java, android, checkbox, onclicklistener, android-checkbox

I have a 'ChecklistItem' class that has the following properties:

```
private CheckBox checkBox;
private ImageButton noteButton;
private TextView vitalField;
```

I have an `onClick Listener` for my checkbox. Now the problem is, when I click on that checkbox and the `OnClick()` method gets called, how can I figure out what ChecklistItem that checkbox is a part of?

Whenever I click on a checkbox, I want to add the `ChecklistItem` that the checkbox is a part of to an array, but the `OnClick()` only knows about the checkbox that called it.

How can I get around this?

Comment: let me get this straight, when you click a checkbox it should add an item to another array, so what is it? string? is it unique ? and in your question you said how to find the class, what do you mean by "class" in here?

Comment: Each checkbox is a member of a ChecklistItem class. This class has several other properties that I need access to once the checkbox object has been clicked. For example, if a ChecklistItem.checkbox is clicked, I want to have access to that ChecklistItem's other properties.

Comment: are you initializing your check boxes from code or XML then assign them to this class instance ? it would be best if you posted how are you linking them

Comment: Initializing the checkboxes in XML and then assigning them to this class instance. I want to associate a checkbox to a ChecklistItem in order to receive information that is connected to the checkbox, such as a TextView member that allows the user to input text after checking the checkbox. So if both the TextView object and CheckBox object are associated with a ChecklistItem class, I can easily access the text in the TextView that is associated with the same Checkbox. Is there a better way to link these objects ?

Comment: you have to group them some how, I asked you to put more code so I don't have to put 1000 lines answer there are too many possibilities in my head, I'm imaganing that you have a view contains a check box and a text view and  an image, when you check the box u might want to enable or disable the text field and do something with the image maybe

so you have a view that you want to use more than once (otherwise you wouldn't need this class) , so why don't you put them and a separate xml file inflate them and add them to your view or maybe use a list view for them

Comment: I don't really know anything about list views, do you know if there is a way to solve this problem without using them? My layout is pretty much a checklist, each "row" having a checkbox, an imageButton and a textView.

Comment: please check my answer and tell me if this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this answer is according to the "long discussion" we had

let's assume you want to make a - re usable - view of your list and you wrote a separate xml layout file called list_item as the following:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"/>
```

so now let's assume you are in the activity or fragment or wherever you want to host your view , NOW I have to point out this is just an example , usually a list view is what you would need in this case but again I have very little details about your app so I'm going to keep it simple

Assuming you have a vertical linear layout and you want to add these "rows" to it, each row represents one of your custom view

```
    LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this); // This inflater is responsible of creating instances of your view
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, layout, false); // This view objects is the view you made in your xml file
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) myView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    TextView textView = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //if checkbox is checked enable textview for example
            // here you have a reference to all the views you just created
            // Weather you want to save them in a class together that's up to you and your app's logic
        }
    });
    layout.addView((myView));
```

if the list is might exceed the screen height you may want to wrap your linear layout in a scroll view.

BTW: ListView is just a neat way to do this automatically by defining how you want each row to appear, and of course it manages your views for you and recycle them when they get of screen, but I just wanted to point out the concept.

Hope this helps you